# Firebase Storage Web - creating reference does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I have tried the exact same thing given in the firebase documentation. But this is the error I get.

```
 functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you have
 the latest SDK by running **npm i --save firebase-functions** inside the
 functions directory.

 functions: Error from emulator. FirebaseError: Error occurred while
 parsing your function triggers.

TypeError: storage.ref is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user1/projects/newproj/functions/index.js:15:26)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:18:11
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/lib/triggerParser.js:32:3)
```

**CODE:**

```
let firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
const storage = firebaseApp.storage();
let storageRef = storage.ref('.../abc.pdf');
```

IDE throws error at **.ref** stating that property *ref* does not exist on *storage*.

**Functions Dependencies:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/functions-emulator": "^1.0.0-alpha.29",
    "express": "^4.16.1",
    "firebase": "^4.6.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.8.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "grpc": "^1.9.0"
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code seems to run in Cloud Functions, which is a server-side Node.js environment. There you use `firebase-admin` to call other Firebase services from your code.

But the `FirebaseStorage.ref()` method you're using comes from the Firebase Storage client-side SDK. It is not available in the Admin SDK.

To see precisely what you can use from `admin.storage`, have a look at the [reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage) and the [Introduction to the Admin Cloud Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start). You'll see that this documentation contains no reference to the `ref()` method you're trying to call.

Comment: That means I cannot have a server side program that can access and provide files on firebase storage based on client request?

Comment: You can. But the SDKs are quite different between client and server. The Firebase Storage server-side SDK is pretty much a thin initialization wrapper around the regular Google Cloud Storage SDK as far as I know.

Comment: Okay thanks. I hope there is some google cloud library that helps me to do this.

Comment: The GCS Node.js library is great for reading/writing files. But I'd definitely use the Firebase client SDKs if you need the result to be available on the client.